# Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: ac at line 9 column 6

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger DupRecError on Account (before insert,before update) {
//List<Account> acList=new List<Account>();
for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
    List<Account> ac=[select id,name,rating from Account where name=:acc.name];
    //acList.add(ac);

  }

  if(ac.size()>0){

  }

}
```

Comment: why you are querying account and and that too inside the for loop,you need declare the list-ac outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn’t seem to do anything in its current form. If you are trying to find duplicate records (as the name of the trigger suggests), you should use instead try to use platform’s duplicate management features..

While you may have other issues here (viz., querying within a loop which needs to be corrected), the immediate issue for the error is that you have the `List<Account> ac` declared in the `for` loop and that you are trying to access it outside the loop.

Without knowing what you are trying to do, an immediate fix will look as below.

```
for(Account acc:Trigger.new){

    // declared here
    List<Account> ac=[select id,name,rating from Account where name=:acc.name];
    ...
    // any variable declared within the loop
    // can be accessed only within that scope
    if(ac.size()>0){
            ...
    }

}

// this was accessed here, outside the scope
/*if(ac.size()>0){
    ...
}*/
```

Comment: Definitely useful to identify the root problem, but this answer likely doesn't help the OP unless you include a remedy.

Comment: Fair point @AdrianLarson. Was on mobile when answered, have added more details now.

Answer (score 0):

Variable ac is declared inside for loop so you can not access that outside that loop.

There is issue in code as well where you are querying data in for loop. It can throw SOQL limit exception as well.  Instead of that you should write code based on below code. This code will get all account name first using loop and then query based on those account name in one go.

```
 trigger DupRecError on Account (before insert,before update) {
    List<string> names=new List<string>();
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
           names.add(acc.Name);
    }
    List<Account> actList=[select id,name,rating from Account where Name=:names];
    if(actList.size()>0){
        system.debug(actList);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide an explanation, otherwise, this might be considered a code dump